# Removing quotation marks in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I used python to import txt data as list. As a result, there are double quotes on the items in the list which i do not want. I want to remove them but I'm currently having some difficulties. I would be glad if someone can kindly help me with this issue.

The list in python is of this nature:

```
lst = ["'BEN','JIM'", "'GIN','ANN'"]
```

I want to have the double quotes removed so I can get this list:

```
lst = ['BEN','JIM', 'GIN','ANN']
```

I tried this lines of code but to no avail:

```
lst = ["'BEN','JIM'", "'GIN','ANN'"]
lst = [x.strip("'") for x in lst] 
lst
```

and the result is not what im expecting:

```
["BEN','JIM", "GIN','ANN"]
```

Again, I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: This sounds like you should change how you import the data. Also, the quotation structure looks like it might be more appropriate to make a 2D data structure or a list of some kind of compound objects - there seems to be an extra layer of structure you're discarding, where `BEN` and `JIM` are grouped and `GIN` and `ANN` are grouped.

Comment: How did you import the data? If you use the `csv` module, you should be able to tell it that the file uses single quotes around the fields and it will strip them.

Comment: Note that the data **does not** contain any quotation marks. It contains apostrophes. The quotation marks are not actually part of the data - they are delimiters to mark the beginning and end of strings. You cannot actually "remove" them - however, if you remove the apostrophes, then Python will switch to using apostrophes instead of quotation marks as delimiters in the display, and it may look like you removed the quotation marks if you don't know how to interpret the output.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - Not in this case. There are two strings in the list and they have csv-like cells using single quotes.

Comment: @tdelaney: Those would be the apostrophes I mentioned.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - As you know, ASCII has apostrophe and quote marks. Python uses both for quoting, calling them "single quote" and "double qoute" - and may alternate them when displaying strings. Since these characters play the role of python quotes, injecting "apostrophe" in the discussion seems distracting to me. We end up with long winded discussions like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `replace()` string function to get rid of the single quotes, and then split on commas.

```
lst = ["'BEN','JIM'", "'GIN','ANN'"]
newlst = []
for pair in lst:
    for name in pair.replace("'", "").split(","):
        newlst.append(name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have confused the display representation of an item as being equivalent to its value.
Look at what you have: a list of two elements:

```
["'BEN','JIM'", 
 "'GIN','ANN'"]
```

You want to obtain a list of four elements:

```
['BEN',
'JIM',
'GIN',
'ANN']
```

You cannot do this by simple character manipulation: the operations you tried do not change the quantity of elements.

Instead, you have to process the elements you have, splitting 2-for-1.
I'll keep the Python technology low ...

```
new_lst = []
for two_name in lst:
    name_pair = two_name.split(',')
    new_lst.extend(name_pair)
```

Output:

```
["'BEN'", "'JIM'", "'GIN'", "'ANN'"]
```

Now you can use your previous technique to remove the single-quotes, leaving you with the four, 3-letter names you wanted.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: You've split the elements but haven't removed the explicit quotes inside the strings.

Comment: Im sorry, this did not solve the problem. Someone posted the solution finally. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The data looks similar to a CSV file where the individual cells are quoted. If it looks like a duck... use a reader to strip them for you. This is a nested list comprehension to first build rows from the the list and then to flatten them to a single list.

```
>>> import csv
>>> lst = ["'BEN','JIM'", "'GIN','ANN'"]
>>> [cell for row in csv.reader(lst, quotechar="'") for cell in row]
['BEN', 'JIM', 'GIN', 'ANN']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ["'BEN','JIM'", "'GIN','ANN'"]
lst = "".join(lst)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
'BEN','JIM''GIN','ANN'
```

Comment: @drtamakloe are you sure this is the correct output? In your question you have stated that desired output is a list: `lst = ['BEN','JIM', 'GIN','ANN']` However, you have accepted the answer that is a string with no comma between Jim and Gin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do thi with list comprehension on two lines:

input:

```
lst = ["'BEN','JIM'", "'GIN','ANN'"]
```

---

```
lst1 = [x.replace("'", "").split(',') for x in lst]
lst2 = [z for y in lst1 for z in y]
```

or on one line

```
lst2 = [z for y in [x.replace("'", "").split(',') for x in lst] for z in y]
```

output:

```
['BEN', 'JIM', 'GIN', 'ANN']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was very helpful.